# Using *ngFor with specific column design

Tags: css, angular

What is the way to make 4 divs under parent that repeated n times? For example:

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let item of items">
        <div class="parent">
            <div>{{item.name}}</div>
            <div>{{item.name}}</div>
            <div>{{item.name}}</div>
            <div>{{item.name}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="parent">
            <div>{{item.name}}</div>
            <div>{{item.name}}</div>
            <div>{{item.name}}</div>
            <div>{{item.name}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The output should be:

```
[1] [2] [3] [4]
[5] [6] [7] [8]
```

Comment: did you try using another *ngFor ??

Comment: What do you want to repeat, the 8 blocks for each item in your items array ?

Comment: Is this just for display purposes or do you really need them in separate divs?

Comment: @Ronnie I need them in separate divs

Comment: only thing I can think of is to preprocess your array and split them into arrays of 4 and then run two `ngFor`s. Your array would look like `items = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]`. Might be another way, but that is what I can think of off the top of my head. If they didn't need to be in divs you could just use index % 4 === 0 and apply a class to every 4th or even use flex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to implement a function that transforms the one-dimensional array into a two dimensional array, such that you can use two *ngFor loops.

Please see this [Stackblitz with a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ee7py4).

Relevant code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container" >  
    <div class="parent" *ngFor="let row of getGroupedItems()" >
        <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of row">{{item}}</div>        
    </div>    
</div>
```

TS:

```
items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7', 'item8']

getGroupedItems() {
    let grouped = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
      const j = Math.floor(i / 4);
      if (i % 4 == 0) {
        grouped[j] = []
      }
      grouped[j].push(this.items[i]);
    }
    return grouped;
  }
```